# .click() sometimes works and sometimes does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, click

the problem I am having is I am trying to apply a click function on a div to a element inside a iframe, it works sometimes but sometimes it doesn't work and it's very random. Here is my code where I apply the click method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var yammerFrame = parent.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[1].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

    $(yammerFrame).load(function() { 
        var yammerMessages = parent.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[1].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById('yammerMessages');

        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $(yammerMessages).click(function() { 
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="text-align: center">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> 
                <span>
                    <a href="https://www.yammer.com/abcam.com/#/threads/company?type=general"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Yammer_logo.png" alt="Yammer" style="width: 200px;height: 50px;"></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center">
                <h4 id="modal-body-sender" style="font-weight:bold"></h4>
                <h4 id="modal-body-date"></h4>
                <div id="modal-body-well" class="well">
                     <h4 id="modal-body-message" style="color:black;word-wrap: break-word;"></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="open_win()">Go To Post</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Site.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body> 
    <span id="yammer-login"></span>
    <div id="yammerDiv">
        <div id="yammerHeader"> 
            <a href="https://www.yammer.com/abcam.com/#/threads/company?type=general"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Yammer_logo.png" alt="Yammer" height="17px;" width="50%"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="yammerMessages" style="margin-top: 25px;">
            <img id="loading-gif" src="http://i559.photobucket.com/albums/ss36/madszckey01/speakker/buffering.gif">
            <div id="text-wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 76%;"> 
                <span id="message"></span>
            </div> 
            <span id="sender"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="yammerButtons" style="display:none">
            <button id="previous" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" aria-label="Left Align" onclick="onPrevious()" dataenter code here-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title="Previous"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="autoscroll()" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title="Auto-Scroll" class='checkbox'>
            <button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" aria-label="Right Align" onclick="onNext()" data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' data-original-title="Next"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show us the HTML where `yammerFrame` contains

Comment: A frame in a frame in an iframe... Really? Also, you have too many closing braces/brackets.

Comment: The main application is using coldfusion which is outdated so yeah its technically built with nested frames D:

Comment: hav u given any `width` and `height` for Id `yammerMessages` by css ??

Comment: yes height is 75% and width is 100%

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I get this issue where click() does not work after user clicks button then the click() functions acts as if it's sleeping when called and you can't wake it up. too much zzzquil maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function with live.

```
$(yammerMessages).live('click', function() { 
        $('#myModal').modal('show');

   });
```

Comment: .live has been depreciated from 1.9. 
[source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

1.9+ should use .on

`$(yammerMessages).on('click', function() { ...`

Comment: @liamfriel I tried that way but still doesn't seem to work sometimes